# Matching elements by class to an array and displaying only elements that match all array values

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have the function below that was originally designed to check multiple checkboxes to see if they were checked and then show any `<p id="com">` with classes that matched those of the "checked" checkboxes. As you can see this function is run on each click of a checkbox.

```
function Checked() {
  var classes = [];
  $('input:checked').each(function(){
    classes.push($(this).attr('class'));
  });
  $('p#com').hide();
  for ( var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++ ) {
    if ($('p#com').hasClass(classes[i])){
    $('p.'+classes[i]).show();
    }
  }
}
Checked();
$(':checkbox').click(Checked);
```

The criteria has now changed ands there are more categories of options required. What I now have is 4 groups of radio buttons. So a maximum of 4 possible checked values, but I would like to show only `<p id="com">` that have classes that match all the array values only. For example

Radio 1 - defines type

Radio 2 - defines finish

I would like to adapt the function to show ONLY classes that match type and finish, not BOTH type and finish separately as it currently does. I am basically stuck and not sure where to go from here, any help would be much appreciated.

The new html would look like this.

```
<div>
  Type<br />
  <input type="radio" name="type" class="manual" />Manual<br />
  <input type="radio" name="type" class="modern" />Modern<br />
  <input type="radio" name="type" class="thermo" />Thermostatic<br />
  <input type="radio" name="type" class="trad" />Traditional
</div>
<div>
  Finish<br />
  <input type="radio" name="finish" class="chrome" />Chrome<br />
  <input type="radio" name="finish" class="antbrass" />Antique Brass<br />
  <input type="radio" name="finish" class="golbra" />Brass - Gold
</div>
    <p class="antbrass manual trad" id="com">Content</p>
    <p class="manual modern chrome" id="com">Content</p>
    <p class="antbrass manual trad" id="com">Content</p>
    <p class="manual modern chrome" id="com">Content</p>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML to go along with it?

Comment: @anthony Missed your comment about 5 times sorry, have edited it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be quite easy if you look at it from the correct viewpoint:

```
var classSelector = $("input:checked")
                    .map(function() { return $(this).attr('class'); })
                    .get().join('.');
$("p." + classSelector).show();
```

What this does is get a list of checked checkboxes with classes e.g. X, Y and Z and produce a string of the form `"X.Y.Z"`. Selecting elements with the selector `"p.X.Y.Z"` will then select just the one you are interested in.

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/PEfBy/)**.

Let me also point out that *giving multiple elements the same `id` as you have done here is wrong*. Ids should be unique inside the DOM. If you want to "tag" multiple items so that you can operate on them as a group, just give them a class instead, for example:

```
<p class="com antbrass manual trad">Content</p> 
<p class="com manual modern chrome">Content</p> 
<p class="com antbrass manual trad">Content</p> 
<p class="com manual modern chrome">Content</p>
```

This does not affect the above solution in any way.

Comment: Thanks Jon, it's my specialty making an easy job harder than it needs to be. I'll go away correct!